# Horizontal progress bar does not update its status

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I am trying to show horizontal progress bar "**Not ProgressDialog**" on my activity like this
[image]

here is what my xml file contains

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pdialog"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:indeterminate="true"
     />
```

I am trying to update its status using AsyncTask Class by setting pdialog.setProgress() but its not showing any progress, it works with progressdialog but not with horizontal progress bar.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor cursor;
private ProgressBar pdialog;
private ImageButton btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.start);
    btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.startbtn);
    pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    pdialog = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pdialog);
    pdialog.setMax(100);
    pdialog.setProgress(20);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pdialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new DownloadFilesTask().execute();

        }
    });
}

private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

    int load = 1;

    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
                load = 10 * i;
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pdialog.setProgress(load);
                    }
                });

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {     

        }   

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        if (progress[0] == 100) {
            pdialog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);          

        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer params) {      

    }

}
}
```

Comment: where your i is incrementing...?

Comment: i have long code so i just cut it to short, i am incrementing [i] in my doinbackground() but its not updataing at all

Comment: have a try with this  any http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/progressBarExample.html and http://blog.webagesolutions.com/archives/170  and also check the value of i correctly whether it incrementing or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `load` variable gets changed correctly:

Instead of this:

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pdialog.setProgress(load);
                    }
                });
```

You could use:

```
publishProgress(load);
```

which would automatically call on UI Thread:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    int p = progress[0];
    if (p >= 100) {
        pdialog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);          
    }else{
       pdialog.setProgress(p);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

remove `android:indeterminate="true"` as pointed out in other answer.

Comment: i tried by putting my setprogress() in OnProgressUpdate but the result is same its nt updating

Comment: @VivekSingh Add a breakpoint at `pdialog.setProgress(p)`, run in debug mode and check: Does code reached this point ?. If it does ,what is value of `progress` variable ?.

Comment: Superb mate.. +1 for remove android:indeterminate="true"

Answer (score 4):

In your layout file please **remove** the following attribute `android:indeterminate="true"` from `ProgressBar` element.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, but
I found the problem is the interface View.OnClickListener().
When the pbar was put out of the  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}), it worked well. Otherwise, it did not update.
Then, I made a constructor which passed the pbar into the OnXXXClickListener.

```html
private class OnXXXClickListener implements View.OnClickListener() {
        private ProgressBar bar;

        public OnXXXClickListener(ProgressBar bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            bar.setProgess(50);
            new DownloadFilesTask().execute();

        }

}
```

Then the pbar could work well.